# Looping code after incorrect user input entry

Tags: java, variables, loops

So I've got a very basic and simple code running at the moment which prompts the user to enter a username, password and account number which is then compared against a hardcoded username, password and account number. I am looking for a way to add the code to a loop so that the user is given THREE chances to enter the username, password and account number correctly (so that it matches the hardcoded ones) before the program terminates. If they enter them wrong THREE times, the program will terminate. Could anyone help me out please, I am a little stuck. My code currently compares the user input with the hardcoded variables but terminates after one incorrect entry.

Thanks

```
import java.io.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Program4 {

static Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);

public static void main(String[] args) {

    final int Username = 3387;
    final int Password = 5183;
    final int AccountNumber = 22334455;

    final int EnteredUsername;
    System.out.println("Enter Username");
    EnteredUsername = console.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Username Entered is " + EnteredUsername);

    System.out.printf("%10s\n", " "); //Ignore these lines, they are just to make the console easier for me to read.

    final int EnteredPassword;
    System.out.println("Enter Password");
    EnteredPassword = console.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Password Entered is " + EnteredPassword);

    System.out.printf("%10s\n", " ");

    final int EnteredAccountNumber;
    System.out.println("Enter Account Number");
    EnteredAccountNumber = console.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Account Number Entered is " + EnteredAccountNumber);

    System.out.printf("%10s\n", " ");

    if (Username == EnteredUsername && (Password == EnteredPassword)
            && (AccountNumber == EnteredAccountNumber)) {

        System.out.println("Authentication Complete!");

    } else {
        System.out.println("Wrong Username, Password or Account Number. Please try again");
        System.exit(0);
    }

}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a do while loop with a counter and a flag. Counter should be used for the 3 tries whereas flag should be used to terminate the loop when entries are valid. Here is a sample:

```
  int attempts = 0; // increment this when wrong crendentials
  boolean authenitcated = false; // set to true when credentials are correct
  do { 
     // your code
   }while(attempts < 3 && authenticated == false)
```

EDIT: Try this

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    final int Username = 3387;
    final int Password = 5183;
    final int AccountNumber = 22334455;

 int attempts = 0;
  boolean authenitcated = false;
  do { 
  final int EnteredUsername;
    System.out.println("Enter Username");
    EnteredUsername = console.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Username Entered is " + EnteredUsername);

    System.out.printf("%10s\n", " "); //Ignore these lines, they are just to make the console easier for me to read.

    final int EnteredPassword;
    System.out.println("Enter Password");
    EnteredPassword = console.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Password Entered is " + EnteredPassword);

    System.out.printf("%10s\n", " ");

    final int EnteredAccountNumber;
    System.out.println("Enter Account Number");
    EnteredAccountNumber = console.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Account Number Entered is " + EnteredAccountNumber);

    System.out.printf("%10s\n", " ");

    if (Username == EnteredUsername && (Password == EnteredPassword)
            && (AccountNumber == EnteredAccountNumber)) {

        System.out.println("Authentication Complete!");
        authenitcated = true;

    } else {
        System.out.println("Wrong Username, Password or Account Number. Please try again");
        attempts ++;

    }
   }while(attempts < 3 && authenticated == false)

}
```

Comment: Okay that sounds like it makes sense. How would I implement this into my code then? I tried adding the samples you gave into my code, but I don't think I'm using them in the correct places.

Comment: @Deponeo Don't like doing this but check my EDIT for the entire code. Hope that works

Comment: Ahh thank you. I had simply missed out `attempts ++;`.

Comment: shouldn't the logic be while attempts <3 and authenticated == false cause once the user is authenticated the prompt ought to stop

Answer (score 0):

Define a counter. Increment the counter in your else block. Check if the counter = 3, only then exit.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class StackFlow {




    public static void main(String[] args) {
      Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);

        final int Username = 3387;
        final int Password = 5183;
        final int AccountNumber = 22334455;

         int EnteredUsername;
         int EnteredPassword;
         int EnteredAccountNumber;
        for(int s=0;s<=3;s++)
        {if (s<3)
        {System.out.println("Enter Username");
        EnteredUsername = console.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Username Entered is " + EnteredUsername);
        System.out.println("Enter Password");
        EnteredPassword = console.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Password Entered is " + EnteredPassword);
        System.out.println("Enter Account Number");
        EnteredAccountNumber = console.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Account Number Entered is " + EnteredAccountNumber);
        if (Username == EnteredUsername && (Password == EnteredPassword)
                && (AccountNumber == EnteredAccountNumber)) {
            System.out.println("Welcome");
            break;
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("Wrong Username, Password or Account Number. Please try again");
        }
        }
            else
        {
            System.out.println("You waste your 3 chances Bye-Bye");
        }
    }

}}
```